# histogram breaks with not continuous break points

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How to set the X-axis in the histogram plot with a predefined break points instead of continuous break points.

```
breaks=c(0,5,10,100,200,1000)
```

The break points are chosen based on the frequency with in the bin ranges. How to achieve this instead of `breaks=c(0,5,10,15,20)` continuous break points ?

Edit:
I have calculated the frequencies separately and plotted using `geom_bar`
[image: expected output]

Expecting similar output with the `hist` plot.

Comment: So you just want to label predefined break points on a ggplot graph?

Comment: @Chris I would like to plot the frequency of the data points in these intervals(break points).

Comment: So you want to plot the number of points that fall in any pre-defined bin, or do you want to make a plot with bins which have a pre-defined number of points in them (i.e., create bins whose widths satisfy a pre-defined inclusion count).

Comment: @Chris Have included the plot, does that answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the problem. but can't you do this already?

```
x <- rnorm(1000, mean= 10, sd= 5)
range(x) # need to have the whole range of x in the histogram
hist(x, breaks= c(range(x)[1], 0, 5, 7, 12, 20, range(x)[2]))

library(ggplot2)
brks=c(range(x)[1], 0, 5, 7, 12, 20, range(x)[2])
ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks= brks) + scale_x_continuous(breaks= brks)
```

You could obviously add `theme(... element_text())` options for whatever formatting you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried this approach and did you observe that though the bins lengths are changed, labels are still the same ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by labels. Reproducible examples are always appreciated

Comment: I meant the labels are `c(-10,-5,0,5,10,15,20,25)` after changing the break points to `c(range(x)[1], 0, 5, 7, 12, 20, range(x)[2])`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can fix that in base graphics, but you certainly can in ggplot via `scale_x_continuous()` ... I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

if you're still interested, maybe something like this:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data("diamonds")
head(diamonds)
c(0,1000,4000,20000) -> breaks
cut(diamonds$price, breaks = breaks) -> diamonds$newprice

diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, newprice) %>% 
  summarise(num = n()) %>%
  as.data.frame -> newdi

ggplot(data = newdi) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = newprice, y = num, fill = cut), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In general, a histogram will have equal sized bins since it's intended as an estimate of the probability distribution.

You could do a count aggregation yourself, and then utilize `geom_bar()` to create a bar chart with your specific bin intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already proceeded with this work around. I was wondering if something can be done using 'breaks' option or any other replacement instead of manual intervention.